Base R grep-family is much faster than `stringr` variants when dealing with factors
I have been using stringr since it's supposed to be faster, but I found out today that it's much slower when dealing with factor terms. I didn't see any warning that this would be the case nor why it is.
For example:
string_options = c("OneWord", "TwoWords", "ThreeWords")

sample_chars = sample(string_options, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
sample_facts = as_factor(sample_chars)

When working with character terms, base R is slower than stringr, as expected. But when dealing with factor terms, base R is like 30x faster.
bench::mark(
    base_chars = grepl("Two", sample_chars),
    stringr_chars = str_detect(sample_chars, "Two"),
    base_facts = grepl("Two", sample_facts),
    stringr_facts = str_detect(sample_facts, "Two")
)

# A tibble: 4 × 13
#  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result            memory             time             gc      
#  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>            <list>             <list>           <list>  
#1 base_chars     116.1ms 116.38ms      8.58    3.81MB        0     5     0      583ms <lgl [1,000,000]> <Rprofmem [1 × 3]> <bench_tm [5]>   <tibble>
#2 stringr_chars  86.04ms   88.2ms     11.3     3.81MB        0     6     0      532ms <lgl [1,000,000]> <Rprofmem [2 × 3]> <bench_tm [6]>   <tibble>
#3 base_facts      3.59ms   3.65ms    271.     11.44MB        0   136     0      501ms <lgl [1,000,000]> <Rprofmem [3 × 3]> <bench_tm [136]> <tibble>
#4 stringr_facts  90.71ms  91.29ms     10.9    11.44MB        0     6     0      549ms <lgl [1,000,000]> <Rprofmem [3 × 3]> <bench_tm [6]>   <tibble>

It looks like stringr isn't doing anything different with factor terms but base R is significantly optimizing it. Is this expected behaviour? Should I report this as a stringr issue? Is there some stringr setting I'm completely missing? I'd like to not have to think about the format of the data to determine if I'm using stringr or base R.

If you look at the code for grepl you can see that there's a special case for factors where it only looks at the values. stringr assumes everything is just a string (as it name kind of implies). They probably didn't choose to special case the factor because it probably doesn't happen that often anymore. R used to default treating character values as factors but it doesn't do that any more. You gotta go out of your way to make a factor.

@MrFlick where in the grepl code is this - the R or the C source?

@SamR it's in R. You can view it by just typing grepl in the console. There's an if (is.factor(x) && length(levels(x)) < length(x)) statement. At least it's there in 4.3.3 which I'm running.

@MrFlick ah I see thanks. Looking at the code, it's because it does grepl(levels(x)) in that case. So it looks like it should be faster for factors when there are a lot more values than unique values - not if you had a factor of random strings. I would think if it's slow enough to matter with a character vector it might be faster to apply the same logic - grepl() the unique values and then subset those.

@MrFlick I should have just looked at the code, but this kind of optimization is what I was assuming. I guess my use-case is non-standard enough to not be included in stringr's design pathway.

It is quicker to search unique values than all elements
As MrFlick pointed out in the comments, this occurs because factors are a special case in grepl() where it matches on the levels, rather than the entire vector. You have a vector with a million elements but only three unique values, so this is a lot less work.
I don't think stringr has an argument to tell it that you are dealing with data with many repeated values. However, you can write a function that applies the grepl() logic to factors with stringr:
str_detect_factor <- function(fct, pattern, negate = FALSE) {
    out <- stringr::str_detect(
        c(levels(fct), NA_character_), pattern, negate
    )
    outna <- out[length(out)]
    out <- out[fct]
    out[is.na(fct)] <- outna
    out
}

This is marginally faster than grepl():
bench::mark(
    base_facts = grepl("Two", sample_facts),
    stringr_facts = str_detect(sample_facts, "Two"),
    stringr_facts2 = str_detect_factor(sample_facts, "Two")
)

#   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 base_facts       3.27ms   4.15ms    220.      11.4MB    112.     49    25      222ms
# 2 stringr_facts   182.1ms 182.44ms      5.44    11.4MB      0       3     0      552ms
# 3 stringr_facts2   3.33ms   3.75ms    252.      11.4MB     96.6    73    28      290ms

Applying this optimisation to character vectors
Your character vector also has many repeated values, so you can apply the same logic. This will not be as fast as with factors, where distinct values are already stored within the object, so you do not have to call unique(). However, it should be faster than the existing approaches:
str_detect_rep <- function(string, pattern, negate = FALSE) {
    unique_string <- c(unique(string), NA_character_)
    out <- stringr::str_detect(
        unique_string, pattern, negate
    ) |> setNames(unique_string)
    outna <- out[length(out)]
    out <- out[string]
    out[is.na(string)] <- outna
    unname(out)
}

We can see it is substantially faster then the base R or stringr versions:
bench::mark(
    base_chars = grepl("Two", sample_chars),
    stringr_chars = str_detect(sample_chars, "Two"),
    stringr_chars2 = str_detect_rep(sample_chars, "Two")
)

# A tibble: 3 × 9
#   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 base_chars      131.2ms  173.1ms      5.80    3.81MB     0        4     0    689.6ms
# 2 stringr_chars     213ms  217.5ms      4.60    3.81MB     2.30     2     1    434.9ms
# 3 stringr_chars2   37.3ms   37.3ms     26.8    42.33MB   295.       1    11     37.3ms

Creating a generic
As your issue was that you did not want to think about whether you were dealing with character or factor data, you can create a generic:
str_detect2 <- function(string, ...) UseMethod("str_detect2")
str_detect2.default <- function(string, ...) str_detect_rep(string, ...)
str_detect2.factor <- function(string, ...) str_detect_factor(string, ...)

Then to benchmark:
bench::mark(
    base_facts = grepl("Two", sample_facts),
    stringr_facts = str_detect(sample_facts, "Two"),
    str_detect2_facts = str_detect2(sample_facts, "Two"),
    base_chars = grepl("Two", sample_chars),
    stringr_chars = str_detect(sample_chars, "Two"),
    str_detect2_chars = str_detect2(sample_chars, "Two")
)

#   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 base_facts          3.77ms    6.3ms    154.     11.44MB     40.3    42    11      273ms
# 2 stringr_facts     197.82ms  207.1ms      4.65   11.44MB      0       3     0      645ms
# 3 str_detect2_facts   3.55ms    4.8ms    190.     11.44MB     43.5    70    16      368ms
# 4 base_chars        121.17ms  125.8ms      7.47    3.81MB      0       4     0      536ms
# 5 stringr_chars     215.54ms  232.9ms      4.36    3.81MB      0       3     0      689ms
# 6 str_detect2_chars   27.5ms   29.2ms     31.2    42.33MB     85.8     4    11      128ms

Now you can just call str_detect2() and not have to think about it - it is faster here character and factor data:


A comparison, also taken stringi into consideration, since stringr is mostly a wrapper around it, basically confirming SamR's and MrFlick's assumptions.
Modified sample_chars and sample_facts to only contain unique values, making the case a little more realistic.
sample_chars <- make.unique(sample_chars)
sample_facts <- as_factor(sample_chars)

Unit: milliseconds
                    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max
              base_chars 649.0219 661.5219 722.4035 693.5823 735.9432 1176.7773
          base_chars_fxd 114.8511 116.5084 125.4108 119.4629 125.0511  201.5845
              base_facts 694.8045 711.7315 769.4673 747.6702 800.0615 1081.8429
          base_facts_fxd 160.9806 165.8422 190.6949 173.8654 214.0473  289.7798
           stringr_chars 411.7234 420.1062 460.1629 437.6956 464.2701  872.4820
           stringr_facts 457.8932 468.9451 510.3969 492.0644 533.0966  711.8716
 stringi_detect_regex_ch 422.2608 432.0969 469.1013 449.2074 475.9340  756.1704
 stringi_detect_regex_fa 468.1434 480.4488 522.0438 504.2079 546.7441  750.5353
   stringi_detect_fxd_ch 118.0593 126.1093 138.3083 133.4033 142.0186  206.6351
   stringi_detect_fxd_fa 163.8008 172.3385 197.7767 181.6919 215.5328  316.5359


library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
    base_chars = {grepl("Two", sample_chars)},
    base_chars_fxd = {grepl("Two", sample_chars, fixed=T)},
    base_facts = {grepl("Two", sample_facts)},
    base_facts_fxd = {grepl("Two", sample_facts, fixed=T)},
    stringr_chars = {str_detect(sample_chars, "Two")},
    stringr_facts = {str_detect(sample_facts, "Two")},
    stringi_detect_regex_ch = {stri_detect_regex(sample_chars, "Two")},
    stringi_detect_regex_fa = {stri_detect_regex(sample_facts, "Two")},
    stringi_detect_fxd_ch = {stri_detect_fixed(sample_chars, "Two")},
    stringi_detect_fxd_fa = {stri_detect_fixed(sample_facts, "Two")}
)

